# Qt: How do I notify changing mouse coordinates to parent object

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qgraphicsscene

I have a little problem with the Qt class `QGraphicsScene`:
To detect the current mouse coordinates I made a new class `QGraphicsScenePlus` with `QGraphicsScene` as the base class. I have already redefined the slot function `mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event)` and the received coordinates seem to be correct. Now I want to notify the parent `QMainWindow` class, where the `QGraphicsScenePlus` object is stored, whenever the mouse coordinates change. What is the best way to do this? I already tried to define signals and slots, but it didn't work. The slot function wasn't found during the execution of the program.

Here is the code so far:

**qgraphicssceneplus.h**

```
#ifndef QGRAPHICSSCENEPLUS_H
#define QGRAPHICSSCENEPLUS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>

class QGraphicsScenePlus : public QGraphicsScene {

public:
    QGraphicsScenePlus(QObject* parent = 0);

public slots:
    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event);

public:
    int mx = 0;
    int my = 0;
};

#endif // QGRAPHICSSCENEPLUS_H
```

**qgraphicssceneplus.cpp**

```
#include "qgraphicssceneplus.h"

QGraphicsScenePlus::QGraphicsScenePlus(QObject* parent) : QGraphicsScene(parent) {

}


void QGraphicsScenePlus::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* mouseEvent) {

    mx = mouseEvent->scenePos().x();
    my = mouseEvent->scenePos().y();

    this->update();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Comment

I am not sure how you made the above code compiled.

**1.** Even though you subclass from a `QObject`, you still need the `Q_OBJECT` macro to keep meta-object compiler informed:

```
class QGraphicsScenePlus : public QGraphicsScene {

    Q_OBJECT    // <--- You miss this

public:
    QGraphicsScenePlus(QObject* parent = 0);
```

**2.** It's not allowed to assign primitive value in C++ class definition, do it in the constructor instead:

```
public:
    int mx /*= 0*/;
    int my /*= 0*/;
};
```

---

### Solution

As for your question:

> What is the best way to do this? I already tried to define signals and slots, but it didn't work.

The best way is still **Signals & Slots**.

### Code

*qgraphicssceneplus.h*

```
class QGraphicsScenePlus : public QGraphicsScene {

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QGraphicsScenePlus(QObject* parent = 0);

public slots:
    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event);

signals:
    void sendCoord(int,int);  // for sending the information of coordinates

public:
    int mx;
    int my;
};
```

*qgraphicssceneplus.cpp*

```
QGraphicsScenePlus::QGraphicsScenePlus(QObject* parent) : QGraphicsScene(parent) {

    mx = 0;
    my = 0;
}
    
void QGraphicsScenePlus::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* mouseEvent) {

    mx = mouseEvent->scenePos().x();
    my = mouseEvent->scenePos().y();

    emit sendCoord(mx, my);  // emit the signal

    this->update();
}
```

To catch the signal, define the slot in `QMainWindow`. For example:

```
public slots:
    void receiveCoord(int x, int y);
```

and connect it to the signal of your graphic scene.

### Demo

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. The problem was the missing Q_OBJECT. That's why my own signals/slots didn't work.