# How could I get the RGB value from QGraphicsScene of a pixel click or hover by mouse in Qt 5?

Tags: c++, image, qt

I'm writing a application. I need to get the position of a image showed in QGraphicsScene, and then get the RGB value of the pixel. How could I do that? It seems that I need to rewrite mouse move event, but I don't know how to do it. It will be great if there is a minimal example.

My code is hosted at [here](https://github.com/hubutui/ImageProcessingKit).

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that I need to rewrite mouse move event, but I don't know how
>   to dot it.

The same way you override any other C++ function. There are tons of examples, and it is an essential part of using the Qt gui C++ API. However, it looks like the one that you need to override is not the mouse move event, but the mouse hover move event:

```
void hoverMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent * e) {
  // get pixel value at coordinates e->pos();
}
```

Conveniently enough, the hover event will give you the position relative to the item.

You will also have to `setAcceptHoverEvents(true)` for the graphics item to enable mouse move events.

Keep in mind you can only get pixel values for `QImage`. So if you are using a `QPixmap` item, you will have to do a lot of conversion to `QImage` each and every time. It will most likely be far more efficient to create your own graphics item that stores a `QImage` internally, and draws that in its paint event.

Comment: Thanks. It seem that I get it wrong. I need to create a custom QGraphicsScene from QGraphicsScene, and then override the mouse event, and add the custom scene to my class. So I override the mouseMoveEvent, at the end of the function, I emit a signal with mouse position. And then I could add a slot to my class. But I'm not sure when or where to connect the signal and slot. Should I do it in the main function or the constructor of my class? If I have not create a object yet, but the signal is emitted, then could the slot work functionally?

Comment: You shouldn't need to override `QGraphicsScene`, `hoverMoveEvent()` is a member of `QGraphicsItem`. There are no signals with `QGraphicsItem`, as it is not a `QObject` derived type. It sounds like you need to do some more learning before you rush into using Qt.

Comment: Yes, I'm beginner of Qt.  I'm considering create a class inherited from QGraphicsScene, and override the mouseMoveEvent. I should emit a signal with mouse position as argument from the mouseMoveEvent function, so I could create a slot later in my class, get the mouse position, convert to proper coordinate, and finally get the pixel's RGB value of a image. If I don't emit a signal in the mouseMoveEvent, how could I pass the position?

Comment: Are you reading what I am writing? Go back and carefully read my previous comment and then my answer. I already gave you everything that is needed to do what you want.

Comment: Hi. I finally get it work. Thank you. I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549882/qt-how-do-i-notify-changing-mouse-coordinates-to-parent-object). And my code is updated in [this branch](https://github.com/hubutui/ImageProcessingKit/tree/ex1-1). May I ask one more question, if you don't mind? If I click the scene before I open an image, my app will quit with segment fault. gdb told me that it's mapFromScene. It seems that the object with a slot which call function mapFromScene is not ready yet, some  the app visit a wrong address. Not sure how to fix this.